# How can i make a workbook in java which accepts dynamic values of string in java?

Tags: java, swing, apache-poi

Its a simple program where i have a text field and i get user input .
i store it in a global variable and create a function to get the file path for the workbook.
however i am made to change it to static and all my files created are named null.
i am using eclipse IDE and apache poi version. 5.0.0.

```
// imported files
public class MyFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    String name;
    JButton button;
    JTextField textField;
    String workbook1() {
        
        String name1="D:\\"+name+".xlsx";
        return name1;
        }
    
    MyFrame(){
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        
        button = new JButton("Submit");
        button.addActionListener(this);
        
        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250,40));
        textField.setFont(new Font("Consolas",Font.PLAIN,35));
        textField.setForeground(new Color(0x00FF00));
        textField.setBackground(Color.black);
        textField.setCaretColor(Color.white);
        textField.setText("username");
        
        
        this.add(button);
        this.add(textField);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource()==button) {
            System.out.println("Welcome "+ textField.getText());
             name=textField.getText();
            //button.setEnabled(false);
            //textField.setEditable(false);
        }
        
    }
    
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    
        
        new MyFrame();
        Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
        Sheet sheet1 = wb.createSheet("Ripon");
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(workbook1());
        wb.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
        wb.close();
    }
    
}
```

*I am just a beginner and any help is appreciated. The code is stolen from BroCode and Stack overflow*

I am trying to create a java application where i can enter details into different columns and rows to create a kind of bill.
I watch tutorial and customize it to my need.

Comment: You create and show the `JFrame` and write the workbook to a file before the user can even read what's on the screen, much less respond.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Take your time studying the tutorial.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I do understand how to create and work  with swing. My issue is when I take a user input  via getText(); I dont get the desired output . The workbook name is set as null cause the static string generated is null.

Comment: I got the answer to my question instead of creating a new global variable i should have made a new form in the void actionPerformed  method.

Comment: Construct and manipulate Swing GUI objects _only_ on the [event dispatch thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer to my question: instead of creating a new global variable I should have made a new form in the `actionPerformed` method.

```java
mainbutton.setText("SUBMIT");
mainbutton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,25));
maintext.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,25));
mainbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == mainbutton) {
            try {
                XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
                Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Data");
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(".\\documents\\"+maintext.getText() + ".xlsx");
                workbook.write(fileOutputStream);
                fileOutputStream.close();
                System.out.println("Workbook saved to file: " + maintext + ".xlsx");
                maintext.setEditable(false);
                mainbutton.setEnabled(false);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
});

//adding stuff to the main frame    
mainframe.add(mainlabelheading,BorderLayout.NORTH);
mainframe.add(mainlabelheading2,BorderLayout.CENTER);
mainframe.add(mainlabelheadingempty,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
gbc.gridx=0;
gbc.gridy=0;
mainlabelheading2.add(mainlabelheading2sublabel1,gbc);
gbc.gridx=2;
gbc.gridy=0;
mainlabelheading2.add(mainbutton,gbc);
gbc.gridx=1;
gbc.gridy=0;
mainlabelheading2.add(maintext,gbc);
```

Did play with the code and found out I was referencing a non static variable from a static method. When I changed the global variable to static it was creating null `.xlsx` files. Then used ChatGPT and stackoverflow to find the answer for my solutions.